# Browserify requires vendor module built with Browserify

Tags: javascript, bower, browserify

I'm having problem with Browserify requiring a vendor library.

The vendor library I'm using is [better-dom](https://github.com/chemerisuk/better-dom/), which is also built with Browserify. I installed it from `bower` and when I'm trying to built, I got:

```
Error: Cannot find module './utils' from '<...>/bower_components/better-dom/dist'
```

Apparently Browserify is trying to parse and process the `requires` statements in the pre-built library. I tried `browserify-shim` and `modulify` with no luck, other attempts are also included below. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

My configuration:

`package.json`:

```
...
"browser": {
  "DOMLegacy": "./bower_components/better-dom/dist/better-dom-legacy.js",
  "DOM": "./bower_components/better-dom/dist/better-dom.js"
},
...
```

`Gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  var bundle = browserify({
    noparse: ["<...>bower_components/better-dom/dist/better-dom.js"]
  });

  bundle.add('./js/all.js');

  // bundle.external("./bower_components/better-dom/dist/better-dom-legacy.js");
  // bundle.external("./bower_components/better-dom/dist/better-dom.js");

  // bundle.transform({ modulify: {
  //   "./bower_components/better-dom/dist/better-dom-legacy.js": "DOMLegacy",
  //   "./bower_components/better-dom/dist/better-dom.js": "DOM"
  // }});

  // bundle.require(
  //   "./bower_components/better-dom/dist/better-dom-legacy.js",
  //   { expose: "DOMLegacy" });
  // bundle.require(
  //   "./bower_components/better-dom/dist/better-dom.js",
  //   { expose: "DOM" }
  // );

  return bundle.bundle()
    .on('error', function(e) {
      console.log(e.toString());
      this.emit('end');
    })
    .pipe(source('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.assets));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out there is a bug in browserify 5 with the `noparse` option.

Workaround: use the old name of this option: `noParse` (still working in browserify 5)

```
var bundle = browserify({
    noParse: ["<...>bower_components/better-dom/dist/better-dom.js"]
});
```

It should fix your build.